# AutoMapper DependencyInjection made easy

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper

I am trying to use AutoMapper with Dependency Injection, the easy way. Say I have a Source and a Destination class with 15 properties. Doing the mapping of some of the properties, I want to use a service, using DependencyInjection.
All the examples I've seen on the net, describe using a ValueResolver (or TypeResolver for the entire class) in which you can do Constructor DI.

Snippet looks like this (using AutoMapper 3.3.1 syntax, but the concept still remains):

```
public class SourceMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(x => x.Value, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<ValueResolver>());
    }

    class ValueResolver : IValueResolver
    {
        private IValueSupplier _valueSupplier;

        public ValueResolver(IValueSupplier valueSupplier)
        {
            _valueSupplier = valueSupplier;
        }

        public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
        {
            Source src = (Source) source.Value;
            return source.New(_valueSupplier.Value * src.MyValue);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach forces me to create a resolver-class for each and every property that requires DI.

I may be missing something, but I can't seem to find any way to type a Lambda Expression-Mapping in AutoMapper, using the DI-provider to provide the implementation of an interface.

So I'd want somthing like this:

```
protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(x => x.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => opt.GetInstance<IValueSupplier>().Value * src.MyValue));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So....I managed to create an extension method which gives me this syntax:

```
protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>().ForMember(x => x.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => opt.Service().OfType<IValueSupplier>().Value * src.MyValue));
    }
```

The Extension method look like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ServiceProvider Service<TSource>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource> mapper)
    {
        var field = mapper.GetType().GetField("_serviceCtor", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Func<Type, object> kernelFunc = field.GetValue(mapper) as Func<System.Type, object>;
        return new ServiceProvider(kernelFunc);
    }

    public class ServiceProvider
    {
        private Func<Type, object> _kernelFunc;

        public ServiceProvider(Func<Type, object> kernelFunc)
        {
            _kernelFunc = kernelFunc;
        }

        public T OfType<T>()
        {
            return (T)_kernelFunc.Invoke(typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

But this is just nasty, right? Can anyone tell me what I have missed, or is AutoMapper simply in need of some DI-syntax improvements?